# group by average in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have data structure (data frame), which contains 3 column, age (integer), weight (float) and height (float), I want to calculate average and median weight/height in each age group (e.g. average weight/height in age 10, average weight/height in age 11, average weight/height in age 12, etc.). Wondering if there are any reference code examples?

Currently, I am doing group-by alike function outside R using Python numpy/pandas package. If there is R built-in solution for group-by, it will be great.

regards,
Lin

Comment: See the documentation for the `by` and `tapply` functions in base R. If you are looking for a package, [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) is a popular package to do this sort of operation.

Comment: @WeihuangWong, vote up and thanks!

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks for the reminder. I will post what I researched next time when asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(age) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = age]
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~age, df1, mean)
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg THe Op is a newbie in R and didn't know about the group by functions.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Based on the description, I was not completely sure about the expected.  So I provided some options.

Comment: I love akrun's comments and reply. R document is sometimes confusing. Answer from akrun is much more clear.

Comment: Vote up for all of akrun's reply. Thanks for the comments from @DavidArenburg, I vote up for your replies as well. I will post what research I did, when I post questions next time. :)